# does pip install -U break virtualenv?

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, virtualenv

I have a virtualenv where I'm running python 2.7.13. I did install numpy a while ago. Today I wanted to install statsmodels as well in the same virtualenv. That's why I did (according to the webpage):

```
pip install -U statsmodels
```

and several packages where updated (numpy among others). I forgot that the -U forces to install the newest version. Since numpy was updated to numpy 1.13.3 I'm not sure if this broke a dependency. Is the forced version 1.13.3 not suitable for the virtualenv? If so how can I remove it and install the correct one. If I'm running

```
pip uninstall numpy
```

followed by a

```
pip install numpy
```

it says:

```
pip install numpy
Collecting numpy
  Using cached numpy-1.13.3-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
Installing collected packages: numpy
Successfully installed numpy-1.13.3
```

Comment: Try `pip install numpy==<version>`

Comment: @Evert but why did in the past when I did pip install numpy not install the newest version? Is it guaranteed that numpy 1.13.3 is compatible with the python version within the virtualenv?

Comment: Perhaps the NumPy package recently updated on PyPI to 1.13.3?

Comment: @Evert thanks. I was not sure about the compatibility with Python. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the compatibility with Python is guaranteed: look at the filename of the wheel that is installed: `numpy-1.13.3-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl`. That matches the Python version you're using (including your OS).

As for `statsmodels` and the upgraded NumPy: if statsmodels requires numpy 1.13.3, you're fine; that's the whole point of a virtualenv: it doesn't break any other dependencies/virtualenvs you might have set up. It is unlikely you have another package in the same virtualenv that requires a lower version of NumPy.